# Extract data from NetCDF using shapefile that consist of mulitiple polygon in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, mask, shapefile, netcdf

I have NetCDF file that has precipitation data for 38 years. I am using shapefile of my area to extract data for my interest region. when I used below code, I get the data corresponding to the grid points that falls inside the polygon. I am however, interested in extracting data based on each polygon of the shapefile (12 in this case) and save the data frame using name of the polygon. Below is my sample code

```
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(GISTools)

NC = brick("Daily_Pcp.nc")
Subbasin_SHP=readOGR("my_Shapefile.shp")
crs(NC)
crs(Subbasin_SHP)
SHP=spTransform(Subbasin_SHP, crs(NC))

Polygon_Names=my_shapefile$Subbasin # there are 12 polygon (subbasins) in my shapefile with specific name

PCP_Data=mask(NC, Subbasin_SHP)
DF=as.data.frame(PCP_Data, xy=TRUE)
DF_insidepoints=DF[complete.cases(DF),]
write.csv(DF_insidepoints, "DataForEntireShapefile.csv")
```

Here is the map of the shapefile with all polygons. I want all the points data that fall in a particular polygon be saved on its polygon name. In total I should get 12 files using `mask` function where as each files has data corresponding to the grid points that falls within that polygon.

```
plot(Subbasin_SHP, col="gray", border="blue", axes=TRUE, pbg="white")
pointLabel(coordinates(Subbasin_SHP), labels = Subbasin_SHP$Subbasin)
```

[image]

Comment: So no body has an answer for this? A work around is to split the shapefile into different polygon and then extract data for each polygon and save it, however, this a very laborus way of completing this task (I have done it this way). There must be an efficient way of solving this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extract function from raster package in combination with stack function.

```
NC=raster::stack("Daily_Pcp.nc") # Stack raster just like brick you did
Subbasin_SHP=readOGR("my_Shapefile.shp") # Read shape file
df=raster::extract(NC,Subbasin_SHP,fun=mean, na.rm=T) #Extract dataframe
```

Any other changes in the dataframe is your choice. example row and column names.